# Question regarding dividing group of people into ordered pair

Tags: probability, combinatorics

This is a very basic counting problem, however I couldn't recall my memory to understand the answer correctly.
From "A First Course in Probability by Sheldon Ross",

> **Example**
>   A football team consists of 20 offensive and 20 defensive players. The players are paired in groups of 2 for the purpose of determining roommates....
>   There are $\dfrac{40!}{(2!)^{20}}$ ways of dividing 40 players into 20 "ordered pairs" of two each.

I tried a smaller set, says:

- Offensive = ${a_1, a_2}$
- Defensive = ${b_1, b_2}$

so all ordered pairs are :
$$a_1a_2, a_2a_1, b_1b_2, b_2b_1$$
$$a_1b_1, b_1a_1, a_1b_2, b_2a_1$$
$$a_2b_1, b_1a_2, a_2b_2, b_2a_2$$
So there are 12 of pairs. Now if I use the formula was given above, I got:
$$\dfrac{4!}{(2!)^2} = \dfrac{4.3.2}{4} = 6$$
which is clearly incorrect.

So my question is, should the formula given from the Example be $\dfrac{40!}{{2!}^{19}}$?

Comment: You're confusing a single pair with a way of ordering all of the players into pairs. (Each way of ordering will consist of more than just a single pair: it will consist of enough pairs to exhaust all the team members.) Also that example seems confusing to me: $40!/2!^{20}$ counts the number of ways to split 40 players into an ordered sequence of subsets each consisting of two unordered people, whereas $40!/20!$ counts the number of ways of splitting 40 players into a set of 20 ordered pairs.

Comment: @anon: Thanks a lot. Dunno why I don't like the wording in probability problems at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are miss understanding the thing, since it is said:

"There are $\frac{40!}{(2!)^{20}}$ ways of dividing 40 players into 20 "ordered pairs" of two each."

which it means that the ordening of the pairs in the set of pairs of a particular combination of pairs matters that pairs are ordered has not sense since the factorial would not have to be in that case with $2$), i.e. in your case would be the possibilities
$$(a_1,a_2),(b_1,b_2)$$
$$(b_1,b_2),(a_1,a_2)$$
$$(a_1,b_2),(b_1,a_2)$$
$$(b_1,a_2),(a_1,b_2)$$
$$(a_1,b_1),(a_2,b_2)$$
$$(a_2,b_2),(a_1,b_1)$$
If the ordening of the pairs in the set of pairs mattered, but not the ordenind of the particular pairs, then the formula would be
$$\frac{40!}{20!}$$
where the denominator represents the way of ordening the $20$ pairs.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It does help ;).